# What should be the next number in the sequence below?

Tags: pattern

Find the next in the sequence below

4035, 8136, 12138, 2928, 1137, ?

This may seem somewhat difficult at first, but is easy when you know what it is related to.
Hints will be given if deemed necessary

Hint 1

> The sequence ends after a certain number of terms

Hint 2

> There are twelve terms in the sequence

Hint 3

> The terms are related to months

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> **7134**

Reason

> The months are arranged in alphabetical order. The first part of the number tells us the month(April=4, August=8, Dec=12 etc..).
>  The second part of the number tells us the number of days in that month, reversed!(April 03 days, August 13 days, Dec 13 days etc..). 
>  The last part of the number tells us how many letters the month have(April - 5 letters, August - 6 letters, Dec - 8 letters).
>  The 6th term of this sequence is July. Using the same reasoning we get **7134**